# basic jquery slider TypeError: $ is not a function on Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am getting this error: "TypeError: $ is not a function $('#slider').list({"

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://plumbsimple.com/wp-content/themes/bootstrapwp-87/js/basic-jquery-slider.min.js"></script>

         <script type="text/javascript">
              window.$ = jQuery;

              $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#slider').list({
                  'animation' : 'slide',
                  'width' : 700,
                  'height' : 300
                });

              });
        </script>
```

Data in header:

```
        <div id="slider"><ul class="list">
        <li><img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' );?>/img/beach.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' );?>/img/hp-computers.jpg"></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: You haven't loaded jquery library

Comment: Many CMS put jQuery into [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode as well, you can re-assign it with `$ = jQuery;` at the beginning of your script if that's the case. I'd personally just `wp_deregister_script('jquery');` or comment its `wp_enqueue_script` line and type the script into the source manually.

Comment: Check if jQuery was loaded properly by placing an alert inside DOM ready event

Comment: @zerkms jQuery is loaded on line 240: http://plumbsimple.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 variants:

1. You have not loaded jQuery library.
2. It is not available by `$` function because of `prototype.js` or something, then try to use `jQuery` function instead of `$`.

Comment: jquery has been loaded on line 241: http://plumbsimple.com/

while line 245 should handle the jQuery conflict: `window.$ = jQuery;`

Answer (score 0):

WP by default puts jQuery in [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode: ([source](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script))

> **Note:** The jQuery library included with WordPress loads in ["no
>   conflict" mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). This is to prevent compatibility problems with other
>   javascript libraries that WordPress can load.

Which can be easily tested on the console:

[image]

So, if you don't use any other library that could conflict with jQuery's `$`, you can re-alias jQuery to `$`:

```
window.$ = jQuery;
```

Put that line at the very beginning of your first script after the jQuery library and it will work fine.

Also, you can just replace all `$` references with `jQuery` or use use a different alias in case you'd have a conflict with prototype or another library.

**edit:** There's something in fact overwriting your global `$` as well. You can wrap your code in an IIFE to create a scope where you can safely use the `$` alias:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#slider').list({
            'animation': 'slide',
            'width': 700,
            'height': 300
        });

    });
})(jQuery);​
```

Comment: I appreciate all the help, but no luck yet. This code starts on line 240:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://plumbsimple.com/wp-content/themes/bootstrapwp-87/js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://plumbsimple.com/wp-content/themes/bootstrapwp-87/js/basic-jquery-slider.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
$ = jQuery;  

$(document).ready(function() {  
           
$('#banner').list({  
 'animation' : 'slide',  
 'width' : 700,  
 'height' : 300  
});  
           
});  
</script>`

Comment: Try with `window.$ = jQuery;`. `=]`

Comment: Yeah, now the error is slightly different -  $ is not a function is in the `$('#banner').list({`, means that it's getting inside DOM ready handler.. I wonder what can be overwriting it.

Comment: interesting yeah, getting closer. Just updated #banner to the correct div ID of #slider but same error as well.

Comment: @user1420650 updated again. `=]` If the last code doesn't work, I guess including the jQuery script manually as `<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` would be the best bet.

Comment: Try with the closure in the last code block, if that doesn't work then you'll probably need one more thinking head. `:P`

Comment: The next problem with your code is that `$.fn.list` is not defined, looking through your includes, `basic-jquery-slider.min.js` defines a `$.fn.bjqs` so you may try replacing `.list` with `.bjqs` also.

Comment: And another thing is that jQuery must be included before the plugins that rely on it. Was looking through your page source, you'll have to move jQuery to the top of those plugins. `=]`

Comment: you're the man! changing back to the general class did the trick.

Comment: No problem, the controls there are not clickable because the `#container` div is overlaying the slider controls. And the plugin doesn't work because `.bjqs` should have `position:relative` or `absolute` (you can define it in the CSS).

Comment: @user1420650 Add this CSS: `<style type="text/css">.bjqs {position:relative;} .bjqs-controls { margin:0; }</style>` to the page and your slider will work. You'll just have to fix the slider positioning to make the controls clickable.

Comment: And `.bjqs-markers { list-style:none; }` to don't show the numbers twice in the list. Rest is just some CSS to adjust it the way you like. Guess this should take care of your WP jQuery issues. `:P` About time for me to call a night, so you can tick this as the [accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/186879) and ask a new question if it's relative to the CSS or something else. Night `=]`

Comment: @user1420650 Now that I think about it, you probably forgot to include a `.css` file from your slider plugin. `:P`

Answer (score 0):

More than likely writing the replace first "$" with "jQuery" and passing the "$" to the function will make that error go away.  Example below.

```
          `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            $('#slider').list({
              'animation' : 'slide',
              'width' : 700,
              'height' : 300
            });

          });`
```

If you looke at the wordpress codex, they provide the solution of what is going on.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script